# MySQL: Count entries without grouping?

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to pull results and count how many of each name is pulled but without grouping...

for example I want this:

```
John Doe 3
John Doe 3
John Doe 3
Mary Jane 2
Mary Jane 2
```

instead of this:

```
John Doe 3
Mary Jane 2
```

Does that make sense?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the reason for not doing a group by? You can get the output you want by joining your original table with a group by query on that table.

Comment: pjp - I don't think he had a problem with using a 'GROUP BY', he just didn't want the final output grouped.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
SELECT b.name, a.the_count
FROM
  some_table b, 
  (SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS the_count
  FROM some_table
  GROUP BY name) AS a
WHERE b.name = a.name
```

Comment: This breaks my query if I also have a join like `INNER JOIN c ON b.name = c.name`. I get `Unknown column b.name in 'on clause'`.

Answer (score 5):

This uses `group by` but gets the output in the format you want.

```
SELECT Name, NG.NameCount
FROM Names
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT Name, Count(1) As NameCount
    FROM Names
    GROUP BY Name) NG
ON Names.Name = NG.Name
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT  mo.*,
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    mytable mi
        WHERE   mi.name = mo.name
        )
FROM    mytable mo
```

Comment: `SELECT  mo.*,
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    mytable mi
        WHERE   mi.name = mo.name and 1=1 and 2=2 and 3=3
        )
FROM    mytable mo WHERE   mi.name = mo.name and 1=1 and 2=2 and 3=3` violates DRY. How can we do this without having to repeat the `where` clause?

Comment: @Pacerier: create a temporary table and write results there first. In other systems we could write a CTE, but MySQL does not support them.

Comment: Are temporary tables a good solution though? Shouldn't we use cursors?

Comment: @Pacerier: To write a query similar to yours, I would use a temporary table and would not use the cursors.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use a subquery, you can also join the table to itself like so:
That would require a subquery.  Perhaps something like this:

```
SELECT t1.name, COUNT(t2.name)
FROM my_table AS t1
INNER JOIN my_table AS t2 ON (t1.primary_key_field = t2.primary_key_field)
WHERE some_conditions
GROUP BY t1.name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `name`,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM `table` AS `alt`
        WHERE `alt`.`name` = `table`.`name`
    ) AS `num`
FROM `table`
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe count over partition?

```
select 
     p.name,
     count(p.name) over (partition by p.name) as counted
from some_table as p
order by counted desc
```

Comment: Is it possible that this solution is only available for MySQL server 8+?