# Is it possible to get results, and count of the results, at the same time? (to filter results based on the result count)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query for which I want to obtain results, and count of the results, at the same time. The filtering of the results is complex, so I can not simply use the subquery trick as in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261189/mysql-count-entries-without-grouping). My ultimate goal is to filter the results based on the result count.

Example:

```
SELECT id, related_info, count(related_info) 
FROM my_table 
WHERE <complex filtering on related_info here>;
```

Results should look like:

```
id | related_info |  count(related_info)|
1  |         info1|                    3|
1  |         info2|                    3|
1  |         info3|                    3|
2  |         info1|                    2|
2  |         info2|                    2|
```

My ultimate goal is to filter the results based on the count, for example:

```
SELECT id, related_info, count(related_info) 
FROM my_table 
WHERE <complex filtering on related_info here> having count(related_info) >=3;`
```

Results should look like:

```
id | related_info |  count(related_info)|
1  |         info1|                    3|
1  |         info2|                    3|
1  |         info3|                    3|
```

(results for `id` 2 are filtered)

I can not use `group by` because I want to get all the results. I can not use a subquery, because it would imply to perform the complex filtering twice.

I don't see any way to perform this with a single query.

Comment: You need to provide source data structure, so we can help you to query it in the way you want.

Comment: @Stoleg: well, you can simply imagine a table with two columns, `id` and `related_info`, the primary key being `(id, related_info)` (so that you get duplicated `id` in the table). I do not want to get the number of rows corresponding to a specific `id`, but the number of rows corresponding to my `where` clause.

Comment: I don't unserstand how you can use an aggregate function without a `GROUP BY` clause and have more than one row in your resultset.

Comment: It was just an example of what I want to achieve, the query is not correct (if it was, I wouldn't be asking this question :p). I know that you always need to use `group by` with an aggregate function. So I am asking for an alternative way to get the kind of results I showed. I think it is not possible, but I ask to the community anyway.

Comment: @Djebel . . . Can you use `rollup` and get the results on another row?

Comment: Wow, I don't know about this `rollup`, could you give an example for my use case please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query:

```
SELECT id, related_info, count(related_info)
FROM my_table
WHERE <complex filtering on related_info here>
group by id, related_info with rollup
```

would produce results like:

```
id | related_info |  count(related_info)|
1  |         info1|                    1|
1  |         info2|                    1|
1  |         info3|                    1|
1  |         NULL |                    3|
```

`rollup` adds an extra row with the summary information.

The solution is easy in most databases:

```
SELECT id, related_info, count(related_info) over (partition by id)
FROM my_table
WHERE <complex filtering on related_info here>
```

Getting the equivalent in MySQL *without* repeating the `where` clause is challenging.

A typical alternative in MySQL, if you need the list of "related_info" is to use `group_concat`:

```
select id, group_concat(related_info), count(*)
from my_table
where <complex filtering on related_info here>
group by id;
```

And a final method, assuming that `related_info` is a single column that uniquely identifies each row:

```
select mt.id, mt.related_info, t.cnt
from my_table mt join
     (select id, group_concat(related_info) as relatedInfoList, count(*) as cnt
      from my_table
      where <complex filtering on related_info here>
      group by id
     ) t
     on mt.id = t.id and
        find_in_set(related_info, relatedInfoList) > 0
```

This turns "related_info" into a list and then matches back to the original data.  This can also be done with a unique id in the original data (which `id` is not based on the sample data).

Comment: This is the best answer so far, but could you then imagine a way of filtering the results based on this `rollup`? Because otherwise, I need an extra filtering step, something I could already do in the first place.

Comment: Does the final result in the question and answer look same? Would you get any other value for `Count(related_info)` other than 1 (except totals)? Then I was answering a completely different question.

Comment: Your updated answer looks fine (while being kind of a hack :p). I am currently evaluating your answer as compared to @Stoleg's :)

Comment: These are two different answers. If you need subtotals and totals - use Gordon's answer, as this is when you would use `partition by` and `rollup`. My answer _is_ a hack, in case you want to have a number from the summary alongside your detail data.

Comment: @Djebel . . . Stoleg's answer is appropriate if the filtering is at the `id` level.  If the filtering is within an id, then the count will be right, but the number of rows wrong.  The `find_in_set()` hack is a way to get around that problem.

Comment: @Stoleg: well, I do want to have a number from the summary alongside my detail data, but your answer does not seem to work as far as I can tell. And yes, Gordon Linoff, the filtering is within an id, you are correct.

Comment: @Djebel, then Gordon's last query is same as mine. I probably should have joined on related info.

Comment: @Stoleg: it would work to join on related info as well, but only if `count(T3.related_info)` was returning the correct value, which is not, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help guys, I really appreciate, I would never have come to this solution on my own. @Stoleg, I thank you as well for the effort, you were close to the solution :p Get my upvotes as thank.

Comment: Cherry on the cake, @GordonLinoff: the `find_in_set` method offers poor performances. Would you have an alternative way of identifying `related_info`s in `relatedInfoList` (a solution that could use indexes)

Comment: @djebel . . . Yes, the performance is not going to be good using this method.  Right now, I cannot think of an alternative that would have better performance.

Comment: Actually, it's fine, the join clause `mt.id = t.id` allows to restrict the results enough for the `find_in_set` to be efficient. For me, this is a problem solved. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Count analytical function. The syntax is COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ...). You can find more here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

Comment: Isn't it SQL Server specific? This question is tagged `mysql`.

Comment: I stand corrected. Analytical functions are only supported on Oracle and MS SQL Server.